# Why the specified operation is performed correctly on the first row of 2d array and substituted with something else on the other two?

Tags: multidimensional-array

I am working on Gaussian algorithm in JavaScript and struggle to figure out how to perform operations on the rows of a matrix. Here, I receive the result which is correct for the 1st row and I noticed that the subtraction is substituted with division[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PzRG.png) on the other two.
Why does it work this way?

I tried to substitute subtraction with addition myself to see what happens. The first row is correct again. But for row two and three A[0][j] is multiplied by 6 instead of 2.[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezp5L.png)